# Call scene in Unity from Android plugin

Tags: java, android, vuforia, unity-game-engine

I have Unity application that is called from another Android application via app links. So, I've created Android Plugin for Unity to handle params sent to app via url. Depending on data from url I want to load one of three scenes defined in my Unity application. I was trying to call gameobject from scene no2 but I've got error: Object not found and scene no0 is loaded.

This is call from Android plugin to Unity:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("ARCamera", "startScene", "some data");
```

It looks like Unity is looking for ARCamera in scene no0 and it is not there, of course.
Is it possibile to call scene that is not defined as starting (0) in Build settings? How?

**EDIT:**

In android:

```
public void startAppP() {
        Log.v(TAG, "starting p");
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("ARCameraP", "loadScene", "sceneP");
    }
```

and in Unity (scene defined as no3) in script attached on object called ARCameraP:

```
public void loadScene(string sceneName)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("HI");
    Application.LoadLevel(sceneName);
}
```

It keeps returning SendMessage: object ARCameraP not found!

I am using older version of Unity because I had some problems with Vuforia. Camera was showing black screen until I downgraded Unity to version 5.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

You can load default scene with by passing in **0** to `SceneManager.LoadScene(0);` but you **can't** use the string overload version of the method  `SceneManager.LoadScene("defaultScene");` until you add the scene in the **Build Settings**.

C# code:

```
public void loadScene(string sceneName)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}
```

Java code:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("NameOfGameObject", "loadScene", "sceneName");
```

Make sure that Scene names are added to the Build Settings. If they are not then use `SceneManager.LoadScene(0);`

Comment: Yes, I am doing something like that... I send name of the scene and according to name I load what I need with Application.LoadLevel("nameofscene"). But problem is that Scene0 is always shown for about one second and then Scene2 or Scene1 (deppending on what should start), I don' want that. It looks like spash screen. I want directly from java code tell which scene to load.
And, everything is added to Build Settings

Comment: @midnightcoffee `Application.LoadLevel("nameofscene")` is deprecated. `SceneManager.LoadScene` replaced it. The code in my answer will directly load scene from Java side. Create a a GameObject called "NameOfGameObject" attach a script to it. Inside that script, put the loadScene function in the scripts. Also call it from Java with the Java code I posted. That should work. If not, post your Java and C# code for further help.

Comment: It keeps returning 
SendMessage: object ARCameraP not found!
but object is in scene and is called like that